# react material-ui domnesting

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

It's really become a pain seeing this much `warning`s regarding `DOMNesting` and I couldn't do anything to get rid of 'em all in one place so here is a typical example of this

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <table> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
table ...
```

Is there any config or command so they all could vanish all of a sudden?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Best way to remove the warnings is to fix the code and bringing out the `table` element from `p` element.
But anyway You can use this line to hide all console warnings:

```
console.warn = () => {};
```

Comment: sure that's the best way but there's not just one warning to handle. thanks for your prompt answer btw.

Comment: I would not recommend doing this,  as it would silence all warnings and potentially lead to serious headaches. You could possibly write a regex filter to drop all those particular warnings though, I guess.

Comment: Yeah I know. I don't recommend changing the console at all. This was just a temporary solution

Comment: @Nathan could you please give an example?

Comment: @HosseinGholamibi I was thinking something like `console.warn = regex check? void : console.warn`, but after looking it up that might not be possible. It's probably best to do what Hamed first suggested and  fix the code. The warnings exist for a reason.

Comment: Having some warnings in the code won't hurt anyone, plenty of production sites have warnings. You can configure your console to hide various levels of warnings and filter text when looking at logs, so you should still be able to find what what you need.

Comment: @Nathan ok I'll drop the quest to hide warnings

Comment: I understand the urge to hide them, I also like a clean warning log, but in the end they're harmless. Anyone who would happen to know how to use developer tools understands that sometimes you get false positive warnings.